# Is it (still) a security flaw to check MIME only by extension?

Tags: security, mime-types

I was working on an HTTP-Server in rust and realized that there aren't any libraries that properly check the MIME type for Files without a "magic number" like JPEG.
I researched and found that "MIME confusion" used to be a problem but was fixed a while ago by browsers like [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/08/26/mitigating-mime-confusion-attacks-in-firefox/).
My question is: Are MIME confusion attacks still a thing? And if so, does that make "getting the mime from file-extension" insecure?

Comment: How would you properly check for a MIME type without a magic number? Making an educated guess à la `file(1)` is fragile. (You also have to be a little careful how you do it in order to not *introduce* type confusion attacks.)

Comment: Interesting, I always assumed that `file` also checked the contents. But from what I read mime confusion shouldn't be an issue, as sniffing completely different types has been blocked by browsers a while ago

Comment: `file` *does* check the contents. It’s not necessarily a good idea to make a guess based on the contents, especially based on something other than a file signature. But yes, this shouldn’t apply to browsers anymore, and you can always specify `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` for older ones.

Comment: I think this question is better asked at [security.se]. But in short: There is no 100% secure way to check what the file is. There are even [polyglot files](https://fahrplan.events.ccc.de/congress/2014/Fahrplan/system/attachments/2562/original/Funky_File_Formats.pdf) which can be many valid document type at once. 
The point is that you should not let the browser guess the content type, but instead explicitly state it. See also https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/